# Why my app crash when i use an intentService to save data?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-intentservice

I am trying to save some data from a file to a database. Everything is fine without using an `intentService`. But, my app crash when i use `IntentService` and i am getting an error om my asyncTask as:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.carl.myTest.AsyncTask.doInBackground(AsyncTask.java:44)
```

and the line 44 is: `HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);`

My problem is why is everything is fine without a service, and chaos after using it?!!! What is going wrong?- Any help is very appreciated. I show my intentService class:

```
 public class TheIntentService extends IntentService {

        MainActivityMyTest t = new MainActivityMyTest ();
        private Handler handler = new Handler();

        public MyIntentService() {
            super("TheIntentService ");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            t.writeToTable();
            handler.post(showResult);
        }

        private Runnable showResult = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Context c = TheIntentService .this.getApplicationContext();
                Toast.makeText(c, "Mission accomplished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Context c = this.getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(c, "Exits service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

and from the MainActivity i start the service like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityMyTest.this, TheIntentService.class);
            startService(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is everything is fine without a service, and chaos after using it?!!!

Because you created your own instance of `MainActivityMyTest`, which appears to be an `Activity`. **NEVER** create an instance of an `Activity`, or `Service`, or `ContentProvider` yourself. Android's framework creates those, not you. Presumably, `MainActivityMyTest` creates `httpclient` somewhere in its lifecycle (e.g., `onCreate()`), and that is not happening.

Please move the code associated with `writeToTable()` into the `IntentService` itself.

Comment: the `writeToTable()` is getting a string from another method! and i am using `broadcastReceiver` to get the result from the `AsyncTask`. Can i move the whole thing  into the `IntentService` itself?!

Comment: @carl: "Can i move the whole thing into the IntentService itself?!" -- I have no idea. What you describe sounds overly complex. More importantly, `IntentService` gives you a background thread; you should not be forking other background threads (including `AsyncTask`) from `onHandleIntent()`. And your `IntentService` cannot be creating instances of activities itself.

Comment: Is it possible to get the `servlet` without using `AsyncTask` when trying  like my example to save some data online?

Comment: Or simply is a bad idea to use `IntentService`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. you explained something important that I did not know before. I will focus on something else for example `to binde a service to an Activity`.